# scrapy regex returning nonmatching urls as well

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

My spider codes are:

```
class TryItem(Item):
    url = Field()

class BbcSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bbc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.bbc.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['.*sport\/0\/tennis\/\d{8}']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        Item = TryItem()
        Item['url'] = response.url
        yield Item
```

Through this spider, I am trying to collect the urls of all the articles on tennis. I use csv code:

```
scrapy crawl bbc_spier -o bbc.csv -t csv
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/34322294
http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/14322295
...
http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/12345678
```

But, the spider also returns nonmatching urls as well, such as:

```
http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/29604652?print=true
http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/34252190?comments_page=11&filter=none&initial_page_size=10&sortBy=Created&sortOrder=Descending
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Just delete all of string after `?` right?

Comment: yes. the url of an article should end with 8 digit numbers. for example, http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/29604652

Comment: Okay, let me check you code.

Comment: I don't know why your code doesn't work, what does `follow=True` do?

Comment: The spider crawls the website using the "follow" rule searching tennis-related articles.

Comment: All right. However the easiest way is:  You can use `re.sub` to remove all of string after `?` before you print them. For example: `re.sub('\?.*', '', 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/29604652?print=True')`

Comment: this will replace all of string after `?` to `''`(empty)

Comment: yes. I could do that. but, I wanted to correct only those urls ending with 8 digit numbers, rather than collecting all and using re.sub. Anyhow, your suggestion is helpful. thanks. I think there is a mistake in my regex.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't know where's wrong. I've tried `re.match('.*sport\/0\/tennis\/\d{8}', 'http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/tennis/296
04652?print=true')` and the output is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let the spider follow the unwanted urls by forcing a url to end after 8 digits:

```
.*sport\/0\/tennis\/\d{8}$
#              IMPORTANT ^
```